# package.json scripts failing on heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, scripting

So I have a series of scripts that are set up to either dev servers for a React/Node Express application OR a production server on heroku. The structure of the app is as follows:

client/package.json //pckg for react app
package.json //pckg for the node server

these are the scripts in the clients package:

```
  "scripts": {
"start": "if-env NODE_ENV=production && npm run start:prod || npm run start:dev",
"start:prod": "node server.js",
"start:dev": "set NODE_ENV=development&& concurrently \"nodemon --ignore 'client/*'\" \"npm run client\"",
"client": "cd client && npm run start",
"seed": "node scripts/seedDB.js",
"install": "cd client && npm install",
"build": "cd client && npm run build",
"heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
```

}

and the only difference between the react apps package.json and the one that is automatically generated with create-react-app is as follows:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:3001/",
```

the way its supposed to run is, install scripts at root folder, run install script to cd into client and install react apps dependencies, then  heroku's post-build script should kick in to run the build script which cds into client and builds a production ready react app. finally the start script should see a NODE_ENV of production and run start:prod.

my problem is that for some reason when i push to heroku, it seems to get stuck on an infinite loop on the install script. I have NO clue why, as the exact same scripts work on other projects PERFECTLY.

<strike>https://github.com/LordKriegan/reactdbdemo</strike>
https://github.com/LordKriegan/reactdbdemo2/ if anyone wants to look at it. (doing a full stack demo for my students :/ not much of a demo if i cant get it deployed)

Comment: "it seems to get stuck on an infinite loop on the install script"—what makes you think this? Please share any error messages you're seeing, or relevant build output. We can't troubleshoot what we can't see.

Comment: its what im seeing in my terminal. when i do a git push heroku master it just keeps repeating
`remote:        > reactdbdemo@1.0.0 install /tmp/build_ffe14cc6afb6dfc4abb1d2091cc50c74
remote:        > cd client && npm install
remote:`

Comment: [Image of terminal](https://imgur.com/wUKPDZI)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working. Forgot create-react-app also initializes a git repo...? either that or somewhere along the way i did an extra git init. anyways i had a .git folder in my client folder, which was preventing my client folder from being pushed up. i ended up creating a new repo and pushing everything to that one and now it works. so incase anyone comes here with a similar problem... make sure you didnt end up in some kind of gitception trap. :/